# How do I make a part of my Regex non-greedy?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-greedy, non-greedy

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
/(\d{1,5}\s[^\d].{5,20}(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))/i
```

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

**Regex**

```
/([0-9]{1,5}.{5,20}(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))/i
```

**Pattern**

```
PO Box 66 23 Britton Drive Bloomfield CT 06002
```

This regex is returning '66 23 Britton Drive'.  I want to return '23 Britton Drive'.  I have tried the following variations of the Regex:

```
/(([0-9]{1,5}.{5,20})?(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))/i - adding a new capturing group and making it uncreedy
/([0-9]{1,5}.{5,20}?(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))/i - making the length of in between characters ungreedy
/([0-9]{1,5}.{5,20}(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))/Ui - adding ungreedy modifier
```

**More Patterns That Don't Work**

```
PO Box 156 430 S Wheeling Dr. Wheeling, IL 60090
```

**Patterns That Do Work**

```
1195 Columbia Dr PO Box 1256 Longview, WA 98632
3400 SW Washington drive PO Box 1349 Peoria, IL 61654
```

Comment: You won't fix it by making anything non-greedy. The fact that a regex matches at the *first* position it can isn't related to greediness.

Comment: How can I rephrase my question to better address this?

Comment: I'm not sure, other than "how can I make this regex match what I want?" It's a tough problem to come up with a perfect solution to.

Comment: `(\d{1,5} [^\d]{5,20}(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))`

Comment: Making that first character not-a-digit is a smart solution.  Here is my final solution, modified with that trick - `/(\d{1,5}\s[^\d].{5,20}(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))/i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^\d]+\d{2} (\d{2} [^ ]+ [^ ]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fEQLU9g36M0EDOtB)

Obviously, i'd need more patterns to make this work for all situations

**Small fix for your current RegEx**

```
(\d{1,5} [^\d]{5,20}(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))
```

Comment: Not-a-digit may be the perfect solution here.

Comment: Yup ... that's a good solution for me.  I had to modify it a little: `/(\d{1,5}\s[^\d].{5,20}(dr|drive)(\.|\s|\,))/i`